# Different arrays in dynamic struct, creation, writting, reading

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct

Strait to the point.
I have a struct with a string, char and int.
The struct is created dynamically because i will need it in different parts of my program.

```
struct A
{
  char staticString[20];
  char* dynamicString;
  char character;
  int integer;
};
```

I know if i want to create a struct i call:

```
A example = (A)malloc(sizeof(A));
```

In order to populate the dynamicString and int i used:

```
example->dynamicString = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
example->integer = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Unfourtanetly when i tried to populate staticString and char it didn't worked.
Don't even ask what was my code for those, i tried a lot of combinations from everywhere.

In addition to that can somebody show me examples how to write/read those values?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dynamicString` is the only thing that needs `malloc` initialization. All other fields can be accessed directly, e.g. `A a = {0}; a.character = 'c'; a.integer = 123; strcpy(a.staticString, "hello");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first:

You're using C, and by the way you've defined the structure, you need to declare the pointer like so:

```
struct A *example;
```

Next, malloc returns a pointer, so you need to cast to a pointer (and not to a structure):

```
(struct A *)malloc(sizeof(struct A));
```

Secondly, I'm not sure why but hey:
 - you're trying to dynamically allocate an int in the structure. As I said previously, malloc returns a pointer, so in your structure you need an int pointer like so "`int *integer;`"
 - you're trying to allocate a dynamic string, however you're not doing it properly, here is what I think you want

```
example->dynamicString = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
```

Where 10 is the size of your dynamic string.

Edit:

you may also populate the integer in your struct statically or dynamically, but I think you intended the static approach:

```
example->integer = 123;
```

The dynamic approach would be (assuming you have `int *integer` in your struct):

```
example->integer = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
*(example->integer) = 123;
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you create a new struct the memory in the heap is set to size of :

sizeof(char)*20 + sizeof(char pointer) +sizeof(char)+ sizeof(int).

If you want to save a string that will be pointed to by your char pointer- then you ask for allocation in heap for the size of that string- and malloc returns the pointer to that memory allocation on heap.

So, you already have a space for your char array, char pointer, char and int that was allocated when you asked to make a new struct and do not need to allocate it again.

also, keep in mind malloc returns a pointer to the allocated place on the heap- so if you malloc(sizeof(int)) you get a pointer to a memory allocation for an int on the heap- which is pointed to by a int pointer Not an int.

good luck!

Comment: Additions of sizeofs is most probably a bad idea. Better sizeof the structure, isn't it?

Comment: @John when you code I agree- but to explain that the 4 bytes (depending on architecture) was allocated when the hole struct was allocated for that int I thought this will make it simpler to get what exactly is done and how much space is allocated  and why there is no need to malloc (sizeof(int)) again.

Comment: Ok, I got you intention now.